# How to read a space delimited file in C using fscanf with restrictions?

Tags: c, stdio, scanf

I have a file that has float numbers separated by spaces and I want to open the file and use the numbers inside this file for mathematical operations (e.g. average), how would I do this using only the following: fopen, fscanf, fclose, printf/scanf, pointers, if/else/switch/loops? (No arrays).

The number of values in the space delimited file can be any amount.

Comment: Yes, I haven't done anything with formatted input yet and I was trying to find good resources for scanf/fscanf.

Comment: `man fscanf` will give a lot of information on exactly what parameters to use.  It might answer all of your questions, especially if your file is just whitespace-delimited.

Comment: If you don't have man pages, I'd recommend http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/

Comment: Are there a fixed amount of numbers per line or just a whole bunch of numbers separated by spaces (no newlines)?

Comment: There is no restriction, floats can be separated with a blank space or a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any knowledge of quantity, you will have to read numbers until you encounter *end of file*, e.g. use a `while` construct.  Keep a running count of the numbers read.

Remember:

1. Check the return value from
   `fscanf`, which tells how many
   values read.
2. Read one number per loop to get
   things working.
3. Test for `EOF` after reading from
   the file, as reading may trigger an
   EOF.
4. Also check for other possible file
   errors.

Comment: Thank's for the reply. After reading the file with a loop, how would I perform operations (like sum,average) on the floats without using an array?

Comment: The `sum` only requires a summation variable.  Add the value read to the `sum`.  After summing all the values, divide by the count and that gives you the average.  Only store the values if you want to do more analysis after the file is read.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It turns out the source of my confusion was what fscanf was doing (e.g. When is it a certain float?), so I'm going to look for more C resources/practice with files.